# Viewing Multiple .DWG files in viewer using Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

I need to see multiple .DWG in the Forge viewer in 3D format. There are some buttons on the viewer screen using which we can toggle between 2D and 3D views. On using those toggle buttons, currently we are able to see only one file at a time in the 3D view. Is there any option to view multiple files in 3D format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use three ways to see multiple views of the same model.

1. Split the screen into multiple screens (SplitScreenExtension): https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Extensions/SplitScreenExtension/
2. Place a view inside a div: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-navigation.sample/blob/master/www/scripts/model.js
3. Creating a div that renders a view within a DockingPanel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I may have already answered this in your other Stackoverflow question, but, it is the same answer here.  Try loading multiple models into a scene, using this blog post as your guide:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-multiple-models-forge-viewer-v7

One neat trick with Forge Viewer, is the ability to load a 2D sheet inside the 3D world.  The 2D sheet, if it comes from DWG, it will be vector lines, and if it's an old PDF, it will be image tiles.

Here's a video of combining 2D sheets into a 3D scene, into something more useful to your user...
[image: 2d-3d-combined]